# Updating value of array

Tags: php, arrays

how do I update the value in itemprices if iteminfo equals to certain subject?

```
User(
[name] => xxxx
[phone] => xxxxx
[email]xxxxx
[itemprices] => Array ( [0] => 1.00 [1] => 1.00 )
[iteminfo] => Array ( [0] => Chemistry [1] => Biology ) 
)
```

Comment: Can you further explain what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach:

```
$subject = 'Chemistry';
$index = array_search($subject, $user->iteminfo);
if (false !== $index) {
  $user->itemprices[$index] = $newvalue;
}
```

Explanation: first you use [**array_search**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the index of the given subject in `iteminfo` array. If it's indeed there, you use that index to update the corresponding value in `itemprices`.

But actually, I'd rather rearrange the data into associative array where all the keys correspond to the subjects, and all the values - to their prices respectively. It's quite easy to do with [**array_combine**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$user->itemdata = array_combine($user->iteminfo, $user->itemprices);
```

Then you won't have to use `array_search` any more, accessing the price info directly by the subject key:

```
$user->itemdata[$subject] = $newvalue;
```

Comment: What if more than one `$subject` exists in iteminfo? (it's a bad array to work with, I agree)

Comment: Then one has to define additional criteria - which of these duplicate subjects' `itemprices` section should be updated. It doesn't seem to be in scope of the given task, however.

Comment: I've tried with the code above, but some of the item it will update all the prices even though I have the condition set for chemistry subject only, why is that so?

Comment: Show the code you're using - it's better if you add it to the question (why isn't there ANY code, btw?), but if it's too large, use pastebin or similar service.